# Accessing more than 5-qubit IBM Quantum Computer

Tags: ibm-q-experience

I'm doing a university project related to Physics using IBM Qiskit. I want to know how to get access to Quantum Computers with more than 5-qubits (preferably more than 10 qubits)? My account information says "Public Access", but is it possible to upgrade it? If not please tell all about the different profiles or status necessary to access different qubits-Quantum Computer.
Thank you

Comment: My answer to a similar question: https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/a/15736/9858

Comment: Thank you. It is helpful to get the idea of results even though there is denial of access to real devices with more than 5 qubits.