# Is it possible to set quantum volume in IBM Quantum simulator?

Tags: qiskit, ibm-q-experience, simulation, quantum-volume

A quantum volume serves as a metric of a quantum processor quality. So far, IBM Quantum provides processors with quantum volume up to 128. Freely accessbile processors have QV up to 32. A user using free access can employ fake processors (see details [here](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/15723/is-it-possible-to-have-access-to-real-quantum-computers-that-have-more-than-15-q)) to simulate behavior of her/his circuits on processor with QV higher than 32.

However what about simulation of processors with QV above 128? Is it possible to somehow set `qasm_simulator` to behave like a processor with given quantum volume?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bear in mind that if you operate on a subset of $n$ qubits, then your QV is at most $2^n$. Hence the answer below assumes that you'd like to experiment with a simulator that has $n$ qubits but some $QV = 2^m$ where $m < n$.

I am not aware of a solution out of the box, but you could:

- specify noise models and coupling map for your simulator
- compute such setup's QV
- iterate on noise parameters until you reach your desired QV.

By definition your simulator has QV essentially equal to 2 to the power of number of qubits, so you are essentially trying to force some limitations onto it.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. However, QV is more or less $2^n$, not $n^2$, right?

Comment: Of course you are right, thank you! I have corrected my answer